# Updating Clob column, but the part of value?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE abc ( details clob);

INSERT INTO abc ( details ) VALUES ( 'img src="/ShowAffix.do?existAttatchList=/nfsc' );
```

I want to update the `details` field of the table to replace the `'ShowAffix'` with the phrase `'showPhoto'`.

Expected output:

```
img src="/showPhoto.do?existAttatchList=/nfsc
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f51c9/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE abc ( details clob);

INSERT INTO abc ( details ) VALUES ( 'img src="/ShowAffix.do?existAttatchList=/nfsc' );

UPDATE abc
SET details = REPLACE( details, 'ShowAffix', 'showPhoto' )
WHERE INSTR( details, 'ShowAffix' ) > 0;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   abc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f51c9/1/0)**:

```
|                                       DETAILS |
|-----------------------------------------------|
| img src="/showPhoto.do?existAttatchList=/nfsc |
```

**Update**:

For large `CLOB`s you can create a function:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bee2db/1)

```
CREATE FUNCTION lob_replace(
  i_lob    IN clob, 
  i_what   IN varchar2, 
  i_with   IN clob,
  i_offset IN INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
  i_nth    IN INTEGER DEFAULT 1
) RETURN CLOB
AS
  o_lob  CLOB;
  n      PLS_INTEGER;
  l_lob  PLS_INTEGER;
  l_what PLS_INTEGER;
  l_with PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  IF   i_lob IS NULL
    OR i_what IS NULL
    OR i_offset < 1
    OR i_offset > DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE
    OR i_nth < 1
    OR i_nth > DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE
  THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;

  n      := NVL( DBMS_LOB.INSTR( i_lob, i_what, i_offset, i_nth ), 0 );
  l_lob  := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH( i_lob );
  l_what := LENGTH( i_what );
  l_with := NVL( DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH( i_with ), 0 );

  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( o_lob, FALSE );
  IF n > 0 THEN
    IF n > 1 THEN
      DBMS_LOB.COPY( o_lob, i_lob, n-1, 1, 1 );
    END IF;

    IF l_with > 0 THEN
      DBMS_LOB.APPEND( o_lob, i_with ); 
    END IF;

    IF n + l_what <= l_lob THEN
      DBMS_LOB.COPY( o_lob, i_lob, l_lob - n - l_what + 1, n + l_with, n + l_what );
    END IF;
  ELSE
    DBMS_LOB.APPEND( o_lob, i_lob );
  END IF;
  RETURN o_lob;
END; 
/
```

And then use it in the update:

```
UPDATE abc
SET details = LOB_REPLACE(
                details,
                'ShowAffix',
                'showPhoto'
              )
WHERE DBMS_LOB.INSTR( details, 'ShowAffix' ) > 0
/
```

Comment: thanks , and there is a small problem, the  clob column have the other value, so need filter.

Comment: @yenpinjen There is a filter on the `UPDATE` statement - however, you have not provided any other details in your question so it is not possible to add any more filtering as **you have not told us** what your other requirements are.

Comment: thanks again, you give a big help, the other question, I will try to finish it.